# Thumbnail doesn't displays correctly in Images Library view

Tags: 2013, list-view, image-display

I changed All Assets view for Images library in SharePoint 2013:

```
  SPList imageList = web.Lists["Images"];
  var view = imageList.Views["All Assets"];                
  view.ViewFields.DeleteAll();
  view.ViewFields.Add("ThumbnailOnForm");
  view.ViewFields.Add("LinkFilename");
  view.ViewFields.Add("Width");
  view.ViewFields.Add("Height");
  view.ViewFields.Add("Modified");
  view.ViewFields.Add("Editor");
  view.Query = @"<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
  view.DefaultView = true;
  view.Update();                           
  imageList.Update()
```

but, when I upload images, then the Thumbnail displays blank image. Only when I add "PreviewOnForm" field to view, then Thumbnail displayed correctly.

How can I display Thumbnail using ThumbnailOnForm column?

Answer (score 1):

I set view xml with PreviewOnForm column, and now it works:

```
var viewXML = @"<View Type='HTML' DisplayName='All Assets' ContentTypeID='0x' ImageUrl='/_layouts/15/images/dlicon.png?rev=23'>
                            <Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>
                            <ViewFields>
                                <FieldRef Name='ThumbnailOnForm' />
                                <FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' />
                                <FieldRef Name='ImageWidth' />
                                <FieldRef Name='ImageHeight' />
                                <FieldRef Name='Modified' />
                                <FieldRef Name='Editor' />
                                <FieldRef Name='PreviewOnForm' Explicit='TRUE' />
                            </ViewFields>
                            <RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>20</RowLimit>
                            <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
                            <Toolbar Type='Standard'/>
                            <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
                            <Aggregations Value='Off' />
                          </View>";
SPList imageList = web.Lists["Images"];
SPView view = imageList.Views["All Assets"];
view.SetViewXml(viewXML);
view.Update();
imageList.Update();
```